# Fixed camera width instead of height?

Tags: unity-game-engine, aspect-ratio

Is it possible to keep the camera width fixed instead of the default setting: height?

Making the height fixed is causing problems for my mobile game (vertical) on multiple devices. Is it possible to change this behavior of the camera?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using an orthrographic or perspective camera? What do you exactly mean by keep the width fixed? As long as you don't change it, it should stay on its value. I also don't understand what you mean by default setting height. The position on the z-Axis?

Comment: perspective camera. When the screen resolution changes, normally the heights stays fixed. That is an issue for vertical games since the device resolution always changes and it completely destroys how wide the game is displayed -- does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the different aspect ratios. I don't think there is a fixed height, the screen just adopts to the given ratio.

If you want to achieve a fixed aspect ratio this unify page will probably help you, it will fill the screen with black bars of devices not fitting your ratio:

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=AspectRatioEnforcer